# knn(k nearest neighbor) density estimation source in matlab

Tags: nearest-neighbor, knn, probability-density

Is there any function/package to perform k-Nearest Neighbor based density estimation in matlab?

or open source..

not knn classification. only density estimation, please.

Comment: Did you ever find this? I would love to use this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My *guess* is no. My search led me to this:

[Classification Using Nearest Neighbors](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/classification-using-nearest-neighbors.html)

where you can see how you can use NN search for classification and:

> You can use kNN search for other machine learning algorithms, such as:
>
> ->  density estimation

On this [link](http://www.ulb.ac.be/di/map/gbonte/mod_stoch/density.pdf) one can find some nice theory on the topics.

PS - I am not sure that there is no such thing you are asking, but it exists, it is very well hidden(which means that not many people use it), thus it probably doesn't exist.